# Trouble displaying Bokeh toolbar

Tags: python, plot, flask, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and Flask python in general but i have managed to create a graph and then output it on my browser via flask. The only problem is that im not getting the "Bokeh tool bar" next to my graph.

My code looks like this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import csv
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.resources import CDN

app = Flask(__name__)


# Create the main plot
    def create_figure():
    xvals = []
    yvals = []
    with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        for row in readCSV:
            xvalue = row[0]
            yvalue = row[1]
            xvals.append(xvalue)
            yvals.append(yvalue)

    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_range=(0, 20))
    p.y_range = Range1d(0, 15)
    p.circle(xvals, yvals, size=10)
    return p
# Index page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    plot = create_figure()
    script, div = components(plot)
    cdn_js = CDN.js_files[0]
    cdn_css = CDN.css_files[0]
    return render_template("index.html", script=script, div=div, 
    cdn_js=cdn_js, 
    cdn_css=cdn_css)
    # With debug=True, Flask server will auto-reload
    # when there are code changes
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

and my index.html code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href={{ cdn_css|safe }} type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ cdn_js|safe }}></script>
</head>
<body>
<H1>First</H1>

{{ script|safe }}
{{ div|safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

Am i missing something? When i output the graph to a output_file i get the toolbar. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is this https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7497 issue. The available workarounds, [as I posted in the thread](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7497#issuecomment-388073715), are as follows:

> There are two options. If you want to keep the toolbar as part of a plot, then you will have to create a `ToolbarPanel` manually and add it with `add_layout()` to a plot. Alternatively you can have a toolbar detached from a plot, as an element of a bigger layout, like it happens with grid plots. In both cases the key is to set `plot.toolbar_location = None`, to disable creation of the default `ToolbarPanel`.

Please follow this issue so that you can be aware of future developments.

Comment: There appears to be a workaround posted by Mateusz himself in the linked thread, @bigreddot - until the bug is fixed this is some pretty critical information, so boosting it out of the thread seems like it'd be of great value to folks like coey; I've gone ahead and edited this answer to do precisely that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I can't explain the reason, but this example works: [realpython github](https://github.com/realpython/flask-bokeh-example/blob/master/tutorial.md)

Comment: The reason this works is because of the INLINE rendering of the js and css. If I add this to my django project and don't rely on the cdn files, it works for me. This makes me think one (or both) of these calls is include code that isn't referenced in the bokeh docs